# Golang - concurrent SSH connections to multiple nodes

Tags: ssh, concurrency, go, channel

I have a fleet of servers that I'm trying to establish SSH connections to, and I'm spawning a new goroutine for every new SSH connection I have to establish. I then send the results of that connection (along with the error(s) (if any)) down a channel, and then read from the channel. This program sort of works, but it freezes in the end even though I close the channel.

This is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"

    "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

// ConnectionResult container
type ConnectionResult struct {
    host    string
    message string
}

func main() {
    cnres := make(chan ConnectionResult)
    ec2svc := ec2.New(&aws.Config{Region: "us-east-1"})
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    params := &ec2.DescribeInstancesInput{
        Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
            &ec2.Filter{
                Name: aws.String("instance-state-name"),
                Values: []*string{
                    aws.String("running"),
                },
            },
        },
    }

    resp, err := ec2svc.DescribeInstances(params)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, res := range resp.Reservations {
        for _, inst := range res.Instances {
            for _, tag := range inst.Tags {
                if *tag.Key == "Name" {
                    host := *tag.Value
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go func(hostname string, cr chan ConnectionResult) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        _, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":22")
                        if err != nil {
                            cr <- ConnectionResult{host, "failed"}
                        } else {
                            cr <- ConnectionResult{host, "succeeded"}
                        }
                    }(host, cnres)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for cr := range cnres {
        fmt.Println("Connection to " + cr.host + " " + cr.message)
    }

    close(cnres)

    defer wg.Wait()
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing concurrent SSH connections in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above is stuck in the `range cnres` `for` loop. As pointed out in the excellent ['Go by Example'](https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels), `range` will only exit on a closed channel.

One way to address that difficulty, is to run the `range cnres` iteration in another goroutine. You could then `wg.Wait()`, and then `close()` the channel, as such:

```
...
go func() {
        for cr := range cnres {
                fmt.Println("Connection to " + cr.host + " " + cr.message)
        }   
}() 
wg.Wait()
close(cnres)
```

On a tangential note (independently of the code being stuck), I think the intention was to use `hostname` in the `Dial()` function, and subsequent channel writes, rather than `host`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I'll post the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Frederik, I was able to get this running successfully:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"

    "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
)

// ConnectionResult container
type ConnectionResult struct {
    host    string
    message string
}

func main() {
    cnres := make(chan ConnectionResult)
    ec2svc := ec2.New(&aws.Config{Region: "us-east-1"})
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    params := &ec2.DescribeInstancesInput{
        Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
            &ec2.Filter{
                Name: aws.String("instance-state-name"),
                Values: []*string{
                    aws.String("running"),
                },
            },
        },
    }

    resp, err := ec2svc.DescribeInstances(params)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, res := range resp.Reservations {
        for _, inst := range res.Instances {
            for _, tag := range inst.Tags {
                if *tag.Key == "Name" {
                    host := *tag.Value
                    publicdnsname := *inst.PublicDNSName
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go func(ec2name, cbname string, cr chan ConnectionResult) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        _, err := net.Dial("tcp", ec2name+":22")
                        if err != nil {
                            cr <- ConnectionResult{cbname, "failed"}
                        } else {
                            cr <- ConnectionResult{cbname, "succeeded"}
                        }
                    }(publicdnsname, host, cnres)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    go func() {
        for cr := range cnres {
            fmt.Println("Connection to " + cr.host + " " + cr.message)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Frederik's solution works fine but with some exceptions. If command group routines (from loop which write to to the channel) execute command with a bit longer response time, processing routine (Frederik's hint) will process and close the channel, before last command routine to finish, so some data loss may occur.

In my case I'm using it to execute remote SSH command to multiple servers and to print response. Working solution for me is to use 2 separate WaitGroups, one for command group routines and second for processing routine. This way, processing routine will wait all command routines to be completed, then process response and close channel to exit for loop:

```
// Create waitgroup, channel and execute command with concurrency (goroutine)
outchan := make(chan CommandResult)
var wg_command sync.WaitGroup
var wg_processing sync.WaitGroup
for _, t := range validNodes {
    wg_command.Add(1)
    target := t + " (" + user + "@" + nodes[t] + ")"
    go func(dst, user, ip, command string, out chan CommandResult) {
        defer wg_command.Done()
        result := remoteExec(user, ip, cmdCommand)
        out <- CommandResult{dst, result}
    }(target, user, nodes[t], cmdCommand, outchan)
}

wg_processing.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg_processing.Done()
    for o := range outchan {
        bBlue.Println(o.target, "=>", cmdCommand)
        fmt.Println(o.cmdout)
    }
}()

// wait untill all goroutines to finish and close the channel
wg_command.Wait()
close(outchan)
wg_processing.Wait()
```